# SNI takes wrong certificate

Tags: apache, certificate, sni

i got the following setup

```
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:443
    <virtualhost *:443>
    Servername  1.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /1
    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache/1.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache/1.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache/1.crt
    </virtualhost>

    <virtualhost *:443>
    Servername  2.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /2
    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache/2.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache/2.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache/2.crt
    </virtualhost>
```

for some reason SNI takes the certificate from 1.domain.com on website 2 resulting in a not secure connection warning page. anyone got an idea why?
i'm using apache  Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
and OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've manged to get it to work, apparently apache requires the namevirtualhost to be in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file instead of the httpd.conf